# ANLTR4 mismatched input

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to write a parser for CAL language but getting these errors

```
line 3:12 mismatched input ')' expecting {'(', '+', '-', True, False, Number, ID}
line 8:4 no viable alternative at input 'func'
line 8:10 mismatched input ')' expecting {If, While, Skipp, Begin, ID}
line 8:11 extraneous input ';' expecting End
```

when running grun cal prog -gui test.cal

my test.cal:

```
void func () is
begin
    return ();
end

main
begin
    func ();
end
```

my cal.g4:

```
grammar cal;

prog: decl_list function_list main Eof;

decl_list: decl SEMI decl_list |;

decl: var_decl | const_decl;

var_decl: Var ID COLON type;

const_decl: Const ID COLON type ASSIGN expression;

function_list: function function_list |;

function: type ID LBR parameter_list RBR Is decl_list Begin statement_block Return LBR expression
    | RBR SEMI End;

type: TypeInteger | TypeBoolean | TypeVoid;

parameter_list: nemp_parameter_list |;

nemp_parameter_list: ID COLON type
    | ID COLON type COMMA nemp_parameter_list
    ;

main: Main Begin decl_list statement_block End;

statement_block: LBR statement statement_block RBR |;

statement: ID ASSIGN expression SEMI
    | ID LBR arg_list RBR SEMI
    | Begin statement_block End
    | If condition Begin statement_block End Else Begin statement_block End
    | While condition Begin statement_block End
    | Skipp SEMI
    ;

expression: frag binary_arith_op frag
    | LBR expression RBR
    | ID LBR arg_list RBR
    | frag;

binary_arith_op: op=(PLUS | MINUS);

frag: ID | MINUS ID | Number | True | False | binary_arith_op frag
      | LBR expression RBR
      | ID LBR arg_list RBR;

condition: TILDE condition
    | LBR condition RBR
    | expression comp_op expression
    | condition op=(OR|AND) condition
    ;

comp_op: EQUAL | NOTEQUAL | LESS | LESSEQUAL | GREATER | GREATEREQUAL;

arg_list: nemp_arg_list |;

nemp_arg_list: ID | ID COMMA nemp_arg_list;

fragment A: 'a' | 'A';
fragment B: 'b' | 'B';
fragment C: 'c' | 'C';
fragment D: 'd' | 'D';
fragment E: 'e' | 'E';
fragment F: 'f' | 'F';
fragment G: 'g' | 'G';
fragment H: 'h' | 'H';
fragment I: 'i' | 'I';
fragment J: 'j' | 'J';
fragment K: 'k' | 'K';
fragment L: 'l' | 'L';
fragment M: 'm' | 'M';
fragment N: 'n' | 'N';
fragment O: 'o' | 'O';
fragment P: 'p' | 'P';
fragment Q: 'q' | 'Q';
fragment R: 'r' | 'R';
fragment S: 's' | 'S';
fragment T: 't' | 'T';
fragment U: 'u' | 'U';
fragment V: 'v' | 'V';
fragment W: 'w' | 'W';
fragment X: 'x' | 'X';
fragment Y: 'y' | 'Y';
fragment Z: 'z' | 'Z';
fragment Digit: [0-9];
fragment Integer: (MINUS? [1-9] Digit*) | '0'+;

COMMA:                  ',';
SEMI:                   ';';
COLON:                  ':';
ASSIGN:                 ':=';
LBR:                    '(';
RBR:                    ')';
PLUS:                   '+';
MINUS:                  '-';
TILDE:                  '~';
OR:                     '|';
AND:                    '&';
EQUAL:                  '=';
NOTEQUAL:               '!=';
LESS:                   '<';
LESSEQUAL:              '<=';
GREATER:                '>';
GREATEREQUAL:           '>=';

Const:                  C O N S T;
Return:                 R E T U R N;
TypeInteger:            I N T E G E R;
TypeBoolean:            B O O L E A N;
TypeVoid:               V O I D;
Main:                   M A I N;
If:                     I F;
Else:                   E L S E;
True:                   T R U E;
False:                  F A L S E;
While:                  W H I L E;
Is:                     I S;
Skipp:                  S K I P;
Var:                    V A R;
Begin:                  B E G I N;
End:                    E N D;


Number: Digit | Integer;
Letter: [a-zA-Z];
ID: Letter (Letter | Digit | '_')*;

WS: [ \t\n\r]+-> skip;
```

I'm not really sure what is causing this even after doing a bit of digging, I thought maybe it was a problem with the test file itself but apparently its my grammar rules causing it. Any ideas what is causing it to be like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going wrong:

You use `Eof`, which should be `EOF`:

```
prog: decl_list function_list main EOF;
```

The `function` rule looks odd:

```
function: type ID LBR parameter_list RBR Is decl_list Begin statement_block Return LBR expression   
        | RBR SEMI End;
```

I think you should remove the `|` at the end: `| RBR SEMI End;` and since you also want to match `return ();`, you should make the `expression` optional. This is probably what you want:

```
function
 : type ID LBR parameter_list RBR Is decl_list Begin statement_block Return LBR expression? RBR SEMI End
 ;
```

Lastly, in your statement_block rule:

```
statement_block: LBR statement statement_block RBR |;
```

you're saying that each block should be wrapped in parenthesis, but looking at your input, this is not the case. So you probably want to do it like this:

```
statement_block: statement statement_block |;
```

which could also just be written like this:

```
statement_block: statement*;
```